# Ruby Native Extension - Manual Compilation

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-native-extensions

I created new Ruby C Extension and hosted it in GitHub,
and I install via Bundler (`gem 'my_cool_gem', git: '..'`).

But when I run the application (`rails s`) I get an error -

`cannot load such file -- my_cool_gem/my_cool_gem`

My current solution, is to manually compile it:

```
$ cd $(bundle show my_cool_gem)
$ rm ext/my_cool_gem/*.o
$ rake compile
```

only then, my app works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you listed the extension in the `gemspec`?

Comment: @matt yes, I listed my extension in `gemspec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misconfigured your `extconf.rb`.

Make sure you have `create_makefile` line to look like:

```
create_makefile(File.join(extension_name, extension_name))
```